# Conversion XHTML to JIRA Markup and vice versa with the AtlassianRenderer

Tags: java, xhtml, jira, confluence, wiki-markup

I have an Java application with Jira integration. The Integration means user may create an issue in the Application format and the Application will transfer it to the Jira Server. And vice versa: user firstly may create an issue on the Jira Server and later it will be trasrfered to the Application.

The application persists issue description in XHTML. Jira persits it in own markup. So I need a converter.

I decided to use an `com.atlassian.renderer:atlassian-renderer` library. XHTML -> jira conversion is pretty easy:

```
private DefaultWysiwygConverter converter= new DefaultWysiwygConverter();
String jiraMarkup = converter.convertXHtmlToWikiMarkup(xhtmlString);
```

But vice versa conversion is unbelievably awfully complex! I can't just call

```
String xhtmlString= converter.convertWikiMarkupToXHtml(newjiraMarkup);
```

`DefaultWysiwygConverter` need to pass a `WikiStyleRenderer` instance. The library doesn't contain a default `WikiStyleRenderer` implementation. It has a `V2RendererFacade`, but its constructor needs a four arguments. Each one of them is abstraction which need to be implemented some way etc etc...

```
public V2RendererFacade(RendererConfiguration rendererConfiguration, LinkRenderer defaultLinkRenderer, EmbeddedResourceRenderer defaultEmbeddedRenderer, Renderer renderer) {
        this.rendererConfiguration = rendererConfiguration;
        this.defaultLinkRenderer = defaultLinkRenderer;
        this.defaultEmbeddedRenderer = defaultEmbeddedRenderer;
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }
```

Is any simple and straight way to do this conversion? Any working examples?